Проблема с выводом в Python
Я хочу парсить сайт вики по террарии и у меня это получилось но проблема вот в чём, когда я пытаюсь вывести текст он выводится слитно типо: я запрашиваю меч зенит мне пишет его крафт
"Терра-клинок«Мяумур»(Издания для ПК, консолей и мобильных устройств)«Звёздный гнев»(Издания для ПК, консолей и мобильных устройств)«Потоковый резонатор»(Издания для ПК, консолей и мобильных устройств)Клинок всадника«Сеятель»(Издания для ПК, консолей и мобильных устройств)«Звёздная ярость»ПчеловодЗачарованный мечМедный кинжал"
как сделать так что бы это всё было не слитно а раздельно?  Вот сам код:
import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = input('Что вы ищете: ')

user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {'user-agent': user}
url = f'https://terraria.wiki.gg/ru/wiki/{a}'
response = requests.get(url, headers=header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

block = soup.find('td', class_='ingredients')
block1 = block.find_all('ul')[0]
f1 = block1.text

print(f1)



Проблема в том, что когда вы получаете текст с помощью .text из элемента ul, все элементы списка (li) объединяются в одну строку без разделителей. Чтобы отобразить текст с разделителями, можно использовать метод .get_text() с разделителем. Например, добавьте разрывы строк между элементами.

хорошо щас попробую, спасибо за ответ

Прочитайте про использование селекторов при парсинге, это сильно упростит решение многих задач.
Начните хотя-бы отсюда
import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# a = input('Что вы ищете: ')
a = 'Мох'
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {'user-agent': user}
url = f'https://terraria.wiki.gg/ru/wiki/{a}'
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')


вариант1
blocks = soup.select('td.ingredients ul li:nth-of-type(1) a:not(.mw-redirect)') 
print(*[b.get('title') for b in blocks], sep='\n')

вариант2
blocks = soup.select('td.ingredients ul li:nth-of-type(1) a.mw-redirect') 
print(*[b.get_text(strip=True) for b in blocks], sep='\n')


Лавовый мох
Криптоновый мох
Ксеноновый мох
Аргоновый мох
Неоновый мох
Синяя замшелая стена
Коричневая замшелая стена
Зелёная замшелая стена
Пурпурная замшелая стена
Красная замшелая стена
Аргоновый мох
Гелиевый мох
Криптоновый мох
Лавовый мох
Неоновый мох
Ксеноновый мох
Лавовый мох
Неоновый мох
Аргоновый мох
Ксеноновый мох
Криптоновый мох
Светящийся поплавок
Светящийся поплавок
Светящийся поплавок
Светящийся поплавок
Светящийся поплавок
Светящийся поплавок
Синий мох
Коричневый мох
Зелёный мох
Пурпурный мох
Красный мох
...


о спасибо за такой разобранный ответ
